# C# ListView Lazy Loading

Tags: c#, listview, winui-3

I would like to have your advise with ListView in a WinUI 3 project (Desktop).
I have a search box where the user can enter keywords and according to them, the results are displayed in a listview.
The listview can contain 0 to more than 10000 entries to display. When the number of items to display is very large, the listview can take more than 6 sec to display the results.

I wonder why it takes so long when the listview handles data virtualization (as if the listview renders all results even though they are not displayed)

I found the following articles in which the authors talk about lazy loading:

[ListView Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51740097/uwp-listview-load-more-%20data-when-listview-scrolling-reaches-to-last-item-infin)

https://platform.uno/blog/lazy-loading-functionality-uno-wasm/

Do you think it is necessary to implement this type of operation when you know that the number of results can be high or am I using the listview wrong?

I use the following code to declare my listview:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="SearchViewResults"
                                  Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.ResultItems}"
                                  IsSourceGrouped="True" />
```

```
<ListView x:Name="SearchListResults"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind SearchViewResults.View, Mode=OneWay}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RowResultTemplate}"                  
                  SelectedIndex="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.ResultsViewVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  Margin="4,0"
                  Height="{x:Bind ViewModel.SearchListResultsHeight, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  MinWidth="800"
                  SelectionChanged="SearchListResults_SelectionChanged"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  ItemClick="SearchListResults_ItemClick"
                  AllowFocusOnInteraction="False">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsStackPanel AreStickyGroupHeadersEnabled="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

</ListView>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you check if your issue is "loading items" or "rendering items"?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I think that the problem is in rendering items. The process to search in the database and add objects to the ObservableCollection is fast. I followed the instructions found in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/listview-and-gridview-data-optimization (section Random access data virtualization) and got better results. Do you know if there are any rules to follow when displaying a large number of elements. Thanks.

Comment: Then the RowResultTemplate item template and the ResultItems class might help to see what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` virtualization is bypassed (meaning it renders all its items) when the `ListView` is in a non-constraining parent.

Make sure your `ListView` is **not** in a `StackPanel` (vertical), `ScrollViewer`, `Grid` in that `Row` that has `auto` size, or any other `Panel` (or `Control`) that offers *infinity* as the available space in the measure phase.

---

Now, like you said, loading the data can be fast so you might not need to implement `ISupportIncrementalLoading`. That's really when you want to add pagination to your data source.

Though, it's always a good idea to [measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072361/what-is-the-best-way-to-measure-how-long-code-takes-to-execute) how long it takes, just to be certain.